# ZSH highlight on tab

Tags: zsh, zshrc

One of the features that I kept hearing about zsh was that it will highlight your selection as you tab through a list of possible choices. Such as choosing a directory to cd into.

[image]

I thought this feature would be enabled automatically, but it doesn't appear to be. At the moment I have this in my .zshrc for git auto completion

```
  zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
  fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)
  autoload -U compinit && compinit
  zmodload -i zsh/complist
```

What else do I have to add to get this effect?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You also need `menu` and `select`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Have been looking for days on how to get this to working (again after new mac setup).