# zsh auto-suggestion list color

Tags: configuration, zsh

I have no idea about which part of the configuration file .zshrc is responsible for **the color of the auto-suggestion list**. The color is now dark blue which is not very eye-friendly with a black background.

The list appears when I type `vim` followed by `TAB`.

The dark blue color is really annoying...

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this post: [Zsh color partial tab completions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300687/zsh-color-partial-tab-completions)

This post is more related to this question:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/is-there-a-way-to-set-coloring-for-cd-tab-complete

In fact,after loading the auto-complete module of zsh, the configuration of the auto-complete list can be done as follows:

`zstyle -e ':completion:*:default' list-colors 'reply=("${PREFIX:+=(#bi)($PREFIX:t)(?)*==34=34}:${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}")';`